# shower drain not snug in mortar

Tags: shower, tile, drain, mortar

Poured shower bed mortar around drain and sloped it properly. Drain is type that screws into base. The face of the drain is square. Now that the mortar is dry and I am ready to tile the shower floor I noticed that there is some play in the drain. It moves a little bit. Is this a big deal?

Comment: Mine is loose because I need to pull it out a couple times a year to flush the drain piping. The loose drain cover is no problem.

Comment: Is the cover loose or the flange not sitting properly on the mortar bed?

Comment: @QuocVu according to most diagrams its the strainer body that is loose. It's the treaded piece and i can twist it a couple centimeters.